# How to alter relative width of ggplot panels in ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am wondering how to alter the relative width of a ggplot within ggarrange. Essentially, I want to have a panel with a control condition next to the experimental data, but I want the control plot to be narrow so it visually takes up less room. I use ggplot and ggarrange to get to the following plot:
[Plot I create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRqnZ.png)

However, I want to make it so that the panel on the left is very narrow. How can I easily (if possible) achieve this in ggarrange/ggplot?

My code and data are as follows:

```
#data
dumpmeans=c(1311.0689, 2422.3053, 3023.9330, 3033.9836, 3671.7638, 4006.7025, 4565.1488, 4191.0641, 2889.3722, 2227.0426, 1534.7433, 1097.0306,  873.9441,  858.0504)
dumpsems = c(91.80183, 95.15943, 129.17323, 109.46287, 152.24321, 178.21212, 137.99762, 147.86416, 111.93688, 114.79679, 131.47547,  80.72197,  61.68696,  57.07458)
dumpday= c(1,8,15,22, 29,36, 43, 50,57, 64,71,78, 85,92)
dumpdf = data.frame(cbind(dumpday, dumpmeans, dumpsems))

nodetmean = 900.8114
nodetsem = 46.16315
nodetday = 0
nodetdf = data.frame(cbind(nodetday,nodetmean,nodetsem))

#control plot
nodetday = ggplot(data = nodetdf)+
  theme_stata(base_size = 20)+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  geom_point(aes(x=nodetday, y=nodetmean), color="black", size =2)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=nodetday, ymin=nodetmean-nodetsem, ymax=nodetmean+nodetsem),color="black", width=.01, 
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,5000), breaks=c(0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(0,0)) +
  xlab("No Detritus Pulse Control") +
  ylab("Seasonal Total Cercarial Density") 
nodetday

#Show exp results
inputdays = ggplot(data = dumpdf)+
  theme_stata(base_size = 20)+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())+
  geom_point(aes(x=dumpday, y=dumpmeans), color="red3", size =2)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=dumpday, ymin=dumpmeans-dumpsems, ymax=dumpmeans+dumpsems),color="red3", width=1, 
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
  xlab("Day of Detritus Pulse") +
  ylab("Seasonal Total Cercarial Density") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 100, by = 15))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,5000), breaks=c(0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000))
inputdays

#make plot with control and exp
totcerc = ggarrange(nodetday, inputdays, ncol=2,nrow=1)
totcerc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `widths` argument to control the width of the plots.

```
totcerc = egg::ggarrange(nodetday, inputdays, ncol=2,nrow=1, widths = c(0.5, 1))
```

Comment: Doesn't it answer your question? I may have not understand you well.

Comment: Oh, it does! I just think it's funny that I missed that argument in ggarrange. Thanks so much !